# Record Live streaming radio

Tags: wordpress, audio-streaming

I would like to be able to record online radio from my wordpress website. Has anyone came across an API or software that can help me archive this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several stream recorders which would do that (e.g.: Tubemaster++, Orbit Stream Downloader, Replay Media Catcher and more) and there is an (expensive) application called Total Recorder, which can record directly from your soundcard (with own system driver to get the sound from the device).
But be aware that not every stream allows you to record, you could have legal problems with this.
But if it is "your wordpress website" I guess this is your music anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions franc. Yes I have privileges to the stream but now I wanted to add a feature on the website (wordpress) where I would allow the users to be able to record the current playing show and download it as a podcast.